# Index out of bounds exception when using recursion in linkedlists

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

So for the most part, I'm required to count the number of elements in the linkedlists using the recursion method. However, I'm being thrown an out of bounds exception. I can't seem to fix the issue.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ListCount {
public static LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 0;
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add("Hi");
list.add("I");
list.add("am");
list.add("a");
list.add("programmer");
list.add("and");
list.add("I");
list.add("am");
list.add("currently");
list.add("working");
list.add("on");
list.add("an");
list.add("assignment");
list.add("that");
list.add("is");
list.add("based");
list.add("on");
list.add("linkedlists");
list.add("for");
list.add("java");

ll = list;

countsize(size);


}
    public static int countsize(int somevalue)
    {
   Iterator next = ll.listIterator(somevalue);  
    {
        if (next == null)
    {
      return 0; 
    }
    else 
    {
    countsize(somevalue + 1);
    }
   System.out.println(somevalue);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 21, Size: 20
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkPositionIndex(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList.listIterator(Unknown Source)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:44)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.countsize(ListCount.java:52)
    at ListCount.main(ListCount.java:38)
```

Comment: Whoever is "requiring" you to count the number of elements in the list via recursion is asking for something really quite ridiculous.  If you have enough elements in the list you will get a stack overflow error regardless of how well your code is written.  A better method would be to count the elements using a while loop or simply call the size() function on the list itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`next` will never be null, because `listIterator` will always return an `Iterator`. What you have to check is if the `Iterator` itself has a next element. So change :

```
if(next == null)
```

to

```
if (!next.hasNext())
```

Comment: This neither... If you don't move the iterator to the next element it will loop forever.

Comment: Ah, such a simple mistake! Works perfectly now, thanks!

Comment: @Domin You don't need to move it, you just want check it if there is a next element...

Comment: @user2336315 This remark is not sufficient to make the code to work. See my answer

Comment: @Dici You may try his code with my solution. He doesn't need the return value, he's printing it. And I didn't say it was the solution, just giving the pointer why he got an infinite recursion... No need to downvote.

Comment: @user2336315 Are you saying that his method is really supposed to return 0 whatever happens ? The printed message has most probably only a debug purpose.

Comment: @Dici I'm only saying what was causing the infinite recursion, no less no more. The OP will be smart enough to change that. The main problem was the null check so why bother me with that?

Comment: @user2336315 To encourage you to give a complete answer instead of a 3 lines one. And if you want me to be able to remove this downvote (which is now locked until the next edit), you will have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is where the problem lies you need to use the interator `next` (rename it to listItr or something to avoid confusion) to get the next element if there is any. Look at the example below:

```
  // Set Iterator at specified index
  Iterator x = list.listIterator(1);

  // Get the next element with the iterator
  if (x.hasNext()) {
     System.out.println(x.next());
  }
```

Using this code you can avoid the `NoSuchElementException` too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to interate.
Replace if(next == null) By if (next.next() == null)

Comment: This won't work if the iterator has no next element (and will throw a NoSuchElementException)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. You need to check `next.hasNext()` when terminating
2. You need to fix the recursion: Currently you methid will always return `0` because you are ignoring the recursive return value

Try this:

```
public static int countsize(int somevalue) {
    Iterator next = ll.listIterator(somevalue);  
    if (!next.hasNext())
        return someValue; 
    System.out.println(somevalue);
    return countsize(somevalue + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The essential problem is your #countsize(int) method recurs without limit until it tries to instantiate an Iterator with a starting index outside the range of your list. The "(next == null)" predicate will never pass because List.listIterator(int) will never return null.

It's just like calling LinkedList.get(int) with the same index - You either get the value at that index (or the Iterator starting at that index for the #listIterator(int) method) or throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException if the index you gave is greater than the highest in the list.

Making some assumptions about the restrictions of your assignment, I'm guessing you're required to use Iterators (rather than just using #get(int)). If that's the case you should probably just instantiate a *single* Iterator using #iterator(void) in the main method and pass this into your count method. That method should recursively check the #hasNext() method before calling #next() and recurring.

Otherwise you could just deal with the IndexOutOfBoundsException in a catch-block?

Answer (score -1):

You are mistaking on several points :

- your construction of the list is too verbose
- your test `next == null` should be `next.hasNext()` but I renamed it to `it`
- you always return 0 whatever happens and never use the result of the recursive call

Here is a working solution :

```
public class ListCount {
    public static LinkedList<String>    ll  = new LinkedList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hi I am a programmer and I am currently working on an assignment that is based on " +
                "linkedlists for java";
        ll = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+")));
        System.out.println(countsize(0));
        System.out.println(ll.size());
    }

    public static int countsize(int somevalue) {
        Iterator<String> it = ll.listIterator(somevalue);
        return it.hasNext() ? countsize(somevalue + 1) + 1 : 0;
    }
}
```